# Node.js virtual memory increases constantly while using child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, heap-memory, child-process

I'm using spawn-child npm package to spawn a shell where i run a binary file which was originally built on C++. I provide Stdin's to the binary and then the binary would be sending out the Stdout's constantly for every second. On the node part once i start receiving the Stdout's from binary i have an `on` listener which would look something like `stdout.on('data', function (data) {})` where i send these data's to the SSE channel.

Everything is working fine but the major concern is the constant memory growth of node process that i see when i hit the binary everytime with an Stdin. I have outlined how my code looks, is there an elegant way to control this memory growth, if so please share.

```js
var sseChannel = require('sse-channel'),
    spawnCommand = require('spawn-command'),
    cmd = 'path to the binary file',
    globalArray = [],
    uuid = require('uuid');

module.exports = function(app) {
  var child = spawnCommand(cmd),
    privateChannel = new sseChannel({
      historySize: 0,
      cors: {
        origins: ['*']
      },
      pingInterval: 15 * 1000,
      jsonEncode: false
    });
  srvc = {
    get: function(req, res) {
      globalArray[uuid.v4()] = res;
      child.stdin.write('a json object in a format that is expected by binary' + '\n'); // req.query.<queryVal>
      child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        privateChannel.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    },
    delete: function(sessionID) {
       var response = globalArray[sessionID];
       privateChannel.removeClient(response);
       response.end();
       delete globalArray[sessionID];
    }
  }
}
```

This code is just to enumerate how it would look in the app. Hitting the Run code snippet would not work in this case.

I collected heapdump at 2 different intervals and this is how the statistics looks, there is a tremendous increase in the Typed Array value, what could be done to maintain or suppress the growth of Typed Array,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you calling `srvc.get()` with every request?

Comment: Yep that is correct. Each time when a request is made there'll be a stdin provided to the binary and the stdout 'on' listener would log the data

Comment: What's the scope of `srvc`? Are you overwriting it on purpose with every module call? Please show us the full code.

Comment: @Bergi, module will run when the node server starts and in the controller i'll be calling the srvc.get() method for every request. I'll furnish the full code..

Comment: @Bergi i added the code for the service fully, hope that helps, if the controller code is also needed i can provide that as well but it is just the router code. (this service resolves as a promise and it's been used in the controller.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're spawning a process once and then adding a new `data` event handler for every request to your http server that never gets removed. So this would explain why the memory usage never drops even after gc.

Another (unrelated) problem is that if you are using your single child process to process multiple incoming requests, you can run into the problem of mixing responses for different requests (you cannot assume that one `data` event will contain *only* the data for a particular request). If the child process is node.js-based, you could set up an ipc channel with it and then just pass regular JavaScript values back and forth instead of setting up `stdout` handling/parsing. If the child isn't node.js-based or you want an alternative (no-ipc) solution, you could set up a queue that all requests get pushed onto and then have a function that processes the queue and responds to each request serially (only moving onto the next request once you have somehow determined you have received all output from the child process for the current request).

If you instead meant for the child process to only be used for a single request, you will need to tweak your code to spawn once per request instead (moving `spawn()` inside `get()`).

Comment: i tried the exact solution which you were proposing but the down side of it is, if i spawn the process for every request then i would end up in having the binary file (C++ app) running for every single request, in this particular case i'll be handling 100's of request so spawning that many number of process would be very expensive.

Comment: That's why I gave multiple solutions to that secondary problem (including: use ipc and/or a queue).

Comment: in this use case i'm dealing with event streams, when a request is made i.e. if a stdin is sent to the child process then the the process would emit data (stdouts) continuously which means i guess i cannot have a queue logic to make subsequent requests once the current request is made.. i mean i make a request and that will be active and then the app should allow any # of active requests..

Comment: there is a restriction to that as well since modern browsers restrict the number of simultaneous connections to the same origin to 6 (that's a different issue) but the essence is here we are dealing with event stream data's.. Even in this case implementing ipc or queue is possible, could you please share some insight on it like links or examples etc.. since i'm pretty new to this terrain

Comment: It's not really possible to give anything more specific since it really depends on (the behavior of) the process being spawned.

Comment: Yeah that's right. The process being spawned is a C++ app which accepts stdin's and emits stdout's... i'm completely off WRT to the technical aspects of it... but i see lot of articles related to memory issue on nodejs when using a child process.. so wondering if i can follow some steps to manage memory from node side effectively..